# Data Skewness is nan or inf

Tags: data-cleaning, numpy, transformation

I have checked the Skewness of my data before applying a Log transformation using the next code :

```
print("Skewness: %f" % df['Wind Speed (km/h)'].skew())
```

and it gave me :

```
Skewness: 1.113493
```

So my data is highly Skewed. Then, I have applied a log transformation using the next code:

```
log_transformed = np.log(df['Wind Speed (km/h)'])
```

and it gave me the next result:

```
Skewness: nan
```

I could not understand why I got this value and what should I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your column contains zeros or negative values.

Note that `np.log(0)` returns `-inf` and `np.log(-1)` returns `nan`, which would explain your computed skewness.

Comment: Yes it contains zeros

Comment: A quick fix would be to use `np.log(x + eps)`with a small `eps`. But that would result in large negative values for all zeros. Maybe a different transform would suit your case better?